# Javascript create custom attribute getter (like in python)

Tags: javascript, web-component

Say I have a class in JavaScript (yes bad bad class, bad class in JS, but its for web components, one has to use classes).

I would like to create a cached attribute getter for elements on a class, in python it would be this:

```py
class Foo(object):
    _elements = {}
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in ['widget1', 'widget2', 'widget3']:  # A long list of items, don't want to create getters for each one individiually
            if not _elements.get(name):
                self._elements[name] = self.getElementById(name)     
            return self._elements[name] 
       else:
            # Default behaviour
            return object.__getattr__(self, name)
```

This is the closest I got, but its ugly to use:

- One must call it as `this.el['widget1']`
- Instead of `this.widget1`

```js
class Foo extends HTMLElement {
    el(id) {
        // Cached get element by id
        this._els = this._els || {};
        if (!this._els[id]) {
            this._els[id] = this.getElementById(id)
        }
        return this._els[id]
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for proxies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: And... why are classes bad?

Comment: @JeremyThille, thats what the internet says when I read about javascript, they say its "syntatic sugar" for prototypes., but I havent figures out prototypes yet.

Comment: Old geezers who learned to code in jQuery days say Classes are bad. They fear change and do not embrace the future. Sensible developers use what is standard in the language, and here to stay for the next (JavaScript) 25 years. Proxies Felix refers to are great, but a regular **cached** getter/setter might suffice for your needs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Add the ``web-component`` tag, I now happened to see this question by clicking your Questions list...

Comment: Thanks @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, I thought it was not too related to web-components thats why I left it out. You seem to be a very helpful Web component guru!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` ***is*** slower

But does your cached performance gain outway extra code, code complexity and time coding?

1 PICO second **equals** 0.00000001 Milliseconds

[image]

```html
<div style="display:grid;grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr">
  <test-component id="CACHED"></test-component>
  <test-component id="BYID"></test-component>
</div>
<div id="DIFF"><b>100.000 calls per run:</b></div>
<script>
  customElements.define("test-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    el(id) {
      this._els = this._els || {};
      if (!this._els[id]) this._els[id] = document.getElementById(id);
      return this._els[id]
    }
    get CACHED() {
      return this.el("CACHED");
    }
    get BYID() {
      return document.getElementById("BYID");
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let count = 100000;
      for (let run = 1; run < 9; run++) {
        let log = [];
        for (let cnt = 0; cnt < count; cnt++) {
          const t0 = performance.now();
          this == CACHED ? this.CACHED : this.BYID;// test performance
          log.push(performance.now() - t0);
        }
        this.average = (log.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / log.length)*1e9;
        let diff = (BYID.average - CACHED.average).toPrecision(2);
        if (this == BYID) DIFF.innerHTML += `<div>Run #${run} = <b>${diff/count}</b> PICO seconds slower per call<div>`;
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: This is a good point, thanks for even running a test, you have a very impressive knowledge of JS. I have removed the complex code, and just use getElementById now. Thanks!

Comment: I did watch a talk that recommend making everything lazy, and only perform actions when requried, or else one has high start up times, but I guess the gain here is neglibable

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has the same issue, this is what I went with, quite a lot of code upfront, but at least its easy to use, e.g. `this.PROGRESS`

```js
class Foo extends HTMLElement {
    el(id, docEl=false) {
        // Cached get element by name
        // Parameter: docEl
        //  Set to true to search the document instead of the shadowRoot
        this._els = this._els || {};
        if (!this._els[id]) {
            const searchNode = docEl ? document : this.shadowRoot;
            this._els[id] = searchNode.getElementById(id)
        }
        return this._els[id]
    }

    // Document Elements
    get TEMPLATE()          { return this.el('TEMPLATE_wc-uploader', true) }
    get TEMPLATE_WC_UPLOAD(){ return this.el('TEMPLATE_wc-upload', true) }
    // Shadow Root Elements
    get PROGRESS()          { return this.el('PROGRESS') }
    get PROGRESS_HEADING()  { return this.el('PROGRESS_HEADING') }
    get DRAG_OVERLAY()      { return this.el('DRAG_OVERLAY') }
    get UPLOAD_LIST()       { return this.el('UPLOAD_LIST') }
```

Comment: You  might want to test this if there really is a performance gain,  getElementId by itself is highly optimized